# Custom Lightning components Lightning for Gmail

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am creating a custom component for Lightning for Gmail.

I want to read the content of email body. I created a test component and a controller for it.

```
<aura:component implements="clients:availableForMailAppAppPage,clients:hasItemContext">
    <aura:attribute name="messageBody" type="String" />
    <ui:button label="Click" press="{!c.myAction}"/>
</aura:component>

myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.get("v.messageBody"));
}
```

But in the console after clicking my button I see only "undefined".

At the same time, if for example I add to the controller `console.log(component.get("v.people").from.name);`, then in the console I can see the sender's name.

Also I tried to remove from the code line `<aura:attribute name="messageBody" type="String" />`, but nothing has changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the message body and people are populated at some point after your component has been created. A few suggested changes to your code:

- Any attributes on an interface that you implement you do not need to specify in your component.
- You'll want to listen to "change" events on the attributes you care about:

  `<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.people}" action="{!c.peopleChanged}" />`

  That will listen to changes to the people attribute. Your component is first created and then these attribute values are populated.
- You can also do things like `cmp.get('v.people.from.email')` that will automatically check for null/undefined for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Braden.I did as you said and event handler `<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.people}" action="{!c.peopleChanged}" />` is triggered, but event handler `<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.messageBody}" action="{!c.bodyChanged}" />` does not work.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, that is strange, I copied your button and handler logic and was able to try this myself and it worked. Here's the source from my component:
https://gist.github.com/nedarb/315464ae529ebad4c85280461b6b4fe9

Comment: I created a new component, copied your code and created another page for GMAIL. But I still see "undefined" in log instead of the email body. This is really strange. http://i64.tinypic.com/2j4f4ew.png

Comment: At github.com the code is named "Custom Salesforce Lightning for Outlook component". Maybe you tried this code for Outlook, not for Gmail?

Comment: You are correct. This is in fact not working as it should. Let me poke around a little and figure out what's going on here.